# java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch, when using PowerMockRunner

Tags: java, java-8, powermock, verifyerror, mrunit

I upgraded the MRUnit version to 1.1.0 in my project, to use the ReduceDriver for testing multiple outputs. After making changes to my test (to make it work with the upgrade), I get this error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 63
Exception Details:
Location: (path to test class)
Reason: Expected stackmap frame at this location.
Bytecode: (Bytecode)
```

My test looks like this (have deliberately removed code to make this more concise):

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MultipleOutputs.class)
public class myReducerTest {
   private ReduceDriver<Text, Text, Text, Text> reduceDriver;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
       reduceDriver = ReduceDriver.newReduceDriver(new myReducer());
   }

   @Test
   public void testHappyPath() throws IOException {
       /*
          Code to declare input key, inout value, expected output, etc.
       */

       reduceDriver.withInput(myInputKey, myInputVal);
       reduceDriver.withMultiOutput("reportName1", key, expectedValue1);
       reduceDriver.withMultiOutput("reportName2", key, expectedValue2);
       reduceDriver.runTest();
   }
}
```

I get the error when I use @PrepareForTest. Note that **myReducer** class has no static or final methods. That is why it is not included in @PrepareForTest annotation. Part of my pom file (I am using maven for building) looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Also note that I am using Java 8, and cannot downgrade to v7 or v6 as mentioned here: [java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733946/java-lang-verifyerror-expecting-a-stackmap-frame-at-branch-target)

I also tried adding the surefire plugin in the pom file, as mentioned here:
[java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 73](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987818/java-lang-verifyerror-expecting-a-stackmap-frame-at-branch-target-73)

None of these solutions work in this case.

Comment: If you think, that anybody suggested adding the surefire plugin to your pom file, you have to work on your reading skills. Really. (And with “reading” I mean “reading and understanding”). I could try to explain further, but if you will read my explanation the same way you read the linked answer, it won’t help.

Comment: @Holger I am new to Java. Maven picks up everything from the POM file while building, so I made an assumption. Check this link http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html Plugin info is under Project/Build

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java. This is only about reading a text and understanding what it says. Nobody said that you should install that plugin. Try to understand the previous sentence.

Comment: Hint: if you are really new to Java, then for your own sake: stay away from PowerMock. PowerMock causes more trouble than good.

Comment: @Jägermeister I have to use PowerMock because the MultipleOutputs class has static methods. Even the ReduceDriver (which is part of MRUnit package) is using PowerMock. Can you suggest alternatives to PowerMock?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check this [issue](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/873). In my case, change to the latest version that worked.Now, my version is 2.0.7

```xml
<properties>
    <powermock.version>2.0.7</powermock.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found this link: 
https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/375.

MRunit 1.1.0 uses PowerMock 1.5.1. which uses JavaAssist 3.18.0-GA.
JavaAssist 3.18.2-GA contains a fix for the verifyError.

Exclude the old PowerMock dependency in MRUnit and replace it with PowerMock 1.5.5 or higher. These PowerMock versions contain the fixed JavaAssist version.

```
    <dependency> (all PowerMock dependencies)
        ... PowerMock dependency ...
        <version>1.5.5(or higher)</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            ...insert all PowerMock exclusions...
        </exclusions>
        <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

As a temporary fix you can add *-noverify* to your JVM arguments. Do not use this in any release though.